# Time Zones in Json Date

Tags: javascript, json, date, timezone, timezone-offset

I am sending Json data via a REST Service to my client. This client should use the data to Display it.

My client uses JavaScript.
I am converting the date in the following way:

```
var from = new Date(myJsonDate.match(/\d+/)[0] * 1);
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
 ...="From":"\/Date(1450134000000)\/" ...
```

My problem is that the dates are correct in Germany but are off by one day in Brazil (e.g. showing Sunday instead of Monday in Brazil).
Does this code use time zones and calculates this accordingly?
How could I turn this off?
I want that the date is displayed exactly how i have sent it.

Comment: That value represents an instant in time - which could very easily be a Monday in Germany and (simultaneously) a Sunday in Brazil...

Comment: If you want the date displayed in a specific timezone, just do that conversion on your client-side.  I recommend moment.js for an easy to use timezone conversion.

Comment: Is that an [epoch time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) value? If so, there's no time-zone embedded in it, that's just absolute time. It's your responsibility to cast it into any local time you need manually. For example, use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/).

Answer (score 1):

The operations with dates in JavaScript have a time zone variation in which the client machine is configured.

Right opportunity had to fix a function that showed difference between dates and nobody knew because. When you instance a date, the return her appears as: “Thu Feb 14 2008 08:41:27 GMT-0300 (Official Hour of Brazil)”
Note that in date has the GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) that indicates in which time zone the date is configured.

I’ll show as avoid the difference of time caused by this in operations with date. To this we have create a function that convert the date always to the time zone that if wait.

```
var calculateTimeZone = function(date, offset) {

    var miliseconds_with_utc = date.getTime() +  (date.getTimezoneOffset() * 60000);
    return new Date(miliseconds_with_utc + (3600000 * offset));

 }
```

Note that in the line 3, we invoke the method getTime() that convert the local moment of date to a number represented by miliseconds since January 1st, 1970 (Unix Epoch). We get the current time zone that is set in browser by method geTimezoneOffset() of API the date in JavaScript and we multiply by miliseconds of  time of a hour. We add then the two values.

Why a hour?

Why this is the time that represents each time zone. By default this method return this time zone in minutes, by this the convertion in hour is necessary.
For to arrive this number 60000 you have that remember that 1 second have 1000 miliseconds and which 1 minute have 60 seconds, then converting minutes for miliseconds we multiply 60*1000 = 60000.

This moment we have the UTC (Coordinated Universal Time) represented by variable “utc” by sum of local moment the time zone in miliseconds.
We need now get a date starting this UTC added with the time zone of destiny, how by example a date expressed in time zone +5 transforming in time zone of brazil (Hour of Brazilian).

Note that in line 5 we got an offset (Time Zone Representation) in hour and converting to miliseconds. Remember that here 1 second have 1000 miliseconds and which 1 hour have 3600 seconds, then convert hour in miliseconds should multiply 1000 * 3600 = 3600000.

We add this result with the value of variable “utc” and we got the moment to the time zone wanted. Thenceforth we create a new date with based in long appropriate and return this new date.

In this way we can maintain of integrity desired in application when we need expressed a date in right time zone.

Comment: Not all time zone offsets are integer multiples of 1 hour. Some have half hours, and some quarter, see [*Wikipedia: List of UTC time offsets*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UTC_time_offsets). Your explanation is overly complex. To adjust any date to another timezone offset, determine the difference between the two offsets and apply it.

Answer (score 1):

> Does this code use time zones and calculates this accordingly?

No. Passing a number to the [*Date* constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date-constructor) is interpreted as a time value, i.e. milliseconds since 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z. Regardless of the settings of the client, it will create a Date for exactly the same instant in time.

However, by default, [*Date.prototype.toString*](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.todatestring) uses the host system settings to apply an offset to the **displayed** values as "local" time.

> How could I turn this off?

Modify the script engine. It's part of the ECMAScript standard so any implementation that doesn't do it is non–compliant.

> I want that the date is displayed exactly how i have sent it.

Either:

1. Send it as a plain string, not as a date
2. Also send the time zone offset of the source so you can apply it at the other end to keep the date the same.

ECMAScript offsets have an opposite sense to most standards, they're -ve for east and +ve for west, so to get a Date with local settings that has the same as the source system:

```
var d = new Date(timevalue);
d.setMinutes(d.getMinutes() + d.getTimezoneOffset() - sourceTimezoneOffset);
```

Where *sourceTimezoneOffset* is the offset of the source system in minutes, +ve for west and -ve for east.

Usually dates related to a specific time zone, so as pointed out, the date in one place might be different to the date in another place at the same instant in time.

Comment: As an addendum, do not hard code a timezone offset depending on location. This will not account for daylight savings. Instead, use the offset that the Date object gives you through Date.prototype.getTimezoneOffset()

Comment: @mienaikoe—perhaps your comment is meant for the OP?

Answer (score 0):

If you are not doing any modifications in dates when sending it from server side, the date will be in the timezone where the server is hosted.

So, if your server is hosted in Germany, dates will be in Germany's timezone.

There would be 2 ways to solve this:

1. Send dates to client in user-timezone from server in the response.
2. Make adjustments in your client application to implement appropriate
   date conversion.

Comment: The value in the OP is simply a time value, it has no timezone.